# Sobel image processing

Tags: c#

My algorithm output is wrong. I tried many solutions, but nothing comes out.
View my result.
[SourceImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeYJq.jpg)

[I'm sorry Lena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4sS.jpg)

```
for (int x = 1; x < fimage.Bitmap.Width - 1; x++)
{
    for (int y = 1; y < fimage.Bitmap.Height - 1; y++)
    {
        double sumX = 0, sumY = 0, sum = 0;

        for ( int i = -1; i <= 1; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = -1; j <= 1; j++ )
            {
                sumX += fimage[y + i, x + j].R * kernel1[i + 1, j + 1];
                sumY += fimage[y + i, x + j].R * kernel2[i + 1, j + 1];
            }
        }

        sum = Math.Sqrt(sumX * sumX + sumY * sumY);
        sum = sum > 255 ? 255 : sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
        fimage[x, y] = Color.FromArgb((byte)sum, (byte)sum, (byte)sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed noise http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: I fixed your formatting, but I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that are fishy:

```
    for ( int j = -1; j <= 1; j++ )
    {
        sumX += fimage[y + i, x + j].R * kernel1[i + 1, j + 1];
        sumY += fimage[y + i, x + j].R * kernel2[i + 1, j + 1];
    }
```

You only respect the red component of the image here, why is that? 
The other major thing is changing the input picture while iterating through it:

```
                sum = Math.Sqrt(sumX * sumX + sumY * sumY);
                sum = sum > 255 ? 255 : sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
                fimage[x, y] = Color.FromArgb((byte)sum, (byte)sum, (byte)sum);
```

You should save the value to a different output image (create a `new Bitmap(fimage.Width, fimage.Height)` with the dimensions from the source image). That could explain the weird diagonal symmetry in your picture, where there's basically a symteric copy of the other side.

Comment: I use red componenet because my image transform to grayscale